# http in angular 2,unable to add records to database

Tags: html, typescript, angular, components

I am trying to post the form data to my database using Angular2 but only the null values are inserted to my database.I am new to angular can someone find the error in my code

My template,

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [(ngFormModel)]="form" #f="ngForm">

       <div class="form-row">
         <div class="formHeading">Facebook</div>
        <input type="text" id="fb" ngControl="facebook">
        <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="f.form.controls.fb.touched &&          !f.form.controls.fb.valid"> Facebook address is required</div>
    </div>


     <div class="form-row">
        <div class="formHeading">Google</div>
        <input type="text" id="gl" ngControl="google"  >
        <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="f.form.controls.gl.touched && !f.form.controls.gl.valid">Google address is required</div>
    </div>


     <div class="form-row">
        <div class="formHeading">Twitter</div>
        <input type="text" id="twt" ngModel = f.twitter >

    </div>


     <div class="form-row">
        <div class="formHeading">LinkedIn</div>
        <input type="text" id="li" >

    </div>



    <div class="form-row">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.form.valid">Save</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

My Component

```
      import {Component} from '@angular/core';
      import {FormBuilder, Validators, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from      '@angular/common';
      import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
      import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
      import {Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

     @Component({
       selector: 'social-form',
       directives:[FORM_DIRECTIVES],
       templateUrl: './components/social/social.html',
       providers: [FormBuilder]
      })

     export class Social {
           http: Http;
           form;
           payLoad = null;

           constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {

          this.form = fb.group({
             "fb": ['', Validators.required],
             "gl": ['',Validators.required],


         });
     }
      constructor(http: Http) {

         this.http = http;
     }
    onSubmit() {


        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        this.http.post('http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/addsocial', JSON.stringify({?????????????}),{headers:headers})
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
             .subscribe((res:Person) => this.form = res);


        }
   }
     class Person{
    facebook:string;
    google:string;
    twitter:string;
    linkedin:string;
   }
```

What should i need to keep in json stringify?
Here i want validations,so i put a constructor similarlly i need http, am i need another constructor?If yes where should i put it since i cannot put two constructors in one component.

Comment: Try `this.form.value`.  Because we can't know in what form your server expects the data how should we be able to make suggestions?

Comment: Its shows the following error, ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one in. Example: <form [ngFormModel]="myCoolForm">

Comment: JSON.stringify({this.form.value}) it says error(expected : insted of .)

Comment: Hi Gunter i posted my errors above

Comment: @Gunter, it shows eoor in console as     
Its shows the following error, ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one in. Example: <form [ngFormModel]="myCoolForm"

Comment: Your question doesn't contain `"myCoolForm"`. I only found `[(ngFormModel)]="form"` while it should be `[ngFormModel]="form"`

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/addsocial. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.         this is new error

Comment: This when you access a server that is different than where your index.html was loaded from. This is not related to Angular. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Oh great the error was cleared,but null values are inserted to my db and i think this is because of this  ......................EXCEPTION: Error in components/social/social.html:2:30b.logError @ bundle.js:22
bundle.js:22 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ngFormModel expects a form. Please pass one in. Example: <form [ngFormModel]="myCoolForm">

Comment: You asked that and I posted a response already above. It's hard from here to see what you're doing exactly.